# VB.net Timeout Expired error with update query

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

```
Dim mm1 As Byte()
Dim mm2 As Byte()
Image2Byte(slogo.Image, mm1)
Image2Byte(ssign.Image, mm2)
Dim cmdupd As New SqlCommand("update config set clinicname=@clinicname,address=@address,doctorname=@doctorname,doctoredu=@doctoredu,mobile=@mobile,email=@email,regno=@regno,logo=@logo,sign=@sign where sno=@sno", sqlConn)
cmdupd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clinicname", clinicname.Text)
cmdupd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address.Text)
cmdupd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doctorname", doctorname.Text)
cmdupd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doctoredu", doctoredu.Text)
cmdupd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regno", regno.Text)
cmdupd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", mobile.Text)
cmdupd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email.Text)
cmdupd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logo", mm1)
cmdupd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sign", mm2)
cmdupd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sno", 1)
cmdupd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

this code giving timeout expired error while insert command with same parameters work even when i give update command in sql management studio its works there but it stucks here in vb.net i searched all over internet but no solutions yet

Comment: There's probably something else going on, but as an immediate work around you can do cmdupd.CommandTimeout = 120 to increase the amount of time it gives your Sql instance to perform the update.

Comment: that i done already no use of it, two filed in table is varbinary(max) for storing images, other tables are updating but not this one.

Comment: So you're saying that an insert works within the standard 30 timeout period but an update doesn't work even if you increase the timeout period to 120 seconds? If you increase the timeout to something huge, does the update ever complete?

Comment: Also, how big are your two `Byte` arrays?  Have you confirmed that something untoward isn't occurring during that conversion?

Comment: [sno] [nchar](10) NULL,
 [clinicname] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [logo] [varbinary](max) NULL,
 [sign] [varbinary](max) NULL,
 [address] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [mobile] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [regno] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [doctorname] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [doctoredu] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [email] [varchar](max) NULL

Comment: i made the timeout to huge but no workout above is the table, and more over if im updating only a text filed not image file than also same error

Comment: as per images the file is less than 100KB

Comment: this query show lenth 93669
SELECT len([logo])
  FROM [pmsdata].[dbo].[config]
GO

Comment: if i remove these two varbinary fields than everything back to normal or if i delete manuly from sql studio all records than insert command with image data work propely and images store properly but not the update sql